# Why do we use @staticmethod?

Tags: python

I just can't see why do we need to use @staticmethod. Let's start with an exmaple.

```
class test1:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value

    @staticmethod
    def static_add_one(value):
        return value+1

    @property
    def new_val(self):
        self.value=self.static_add_one(self.value)
        return self.value


a=test1(3)
print(a.new_val) ## >>> 4



class test2:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value

    def static_add_one(self,value):
        return value+1

    @property
    def new_val(self):
        self.value=self.static_add_one(self.value)
        return self.value


b=test2(3)
print(b.new_val) ## >>> 4
```

In the example above, the method, `static_add_one` , in the two classes do not require the instance of the class(self) in calculation.

The method `static_add_one` in the class `test1` is decorated by `@staticmethod` and work properly.

But at the same time, the method `static_add_one` in the class `test2` which has no `@staticmethod` decoration also works properly by using a trick that provides a `self` in the argument but doesn't use it at all.

So what is the benefit of using `@staticmethod`? Does it improve the performance? Or is it just due to the zen of python which states that "*Explicit is better than implicit*"?

Comment: For the most part, just use module-level functions and forget `@staticmethod`s exist.

Comment: To make java programmers happy.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams : May I ask for the reason of why we shouldn't use `test.static_add_one`?

Comment: Because adding 1 to an arbitrary object has essentially nothing to do with the class.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Some method doesn't require the class but the class requires those methods to perform some calculation. Where should I put those methods? Module-level? Or do you mean I should write functions like get_new_value() and set_new_value(value) which interact with the instance of class directly?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The reason to use `staticmethod` is if you have something that could be written as a standalone function (not part of any class), but you want to keep it within the class because it's somehow semantically related to the class.  (For instance, it could be a function that doesn't require any information from the class, but whose behavior is specific to the class, so that subclasses might want to override it.)  In many cases, it could make just as much sense to write something as a standalone function instead of a staticmethod.

Your example isn't really the same.  A key difference is that, even though you don't use `self`, you still need an instance to call `static_add_one` --- you can't call it directly on the class with `test2.static_add_one(1)`.  So there is a genuine difference in behavior there.  The most serious "rival" to a staticmethod isn't a regular method that ignores `self`, but a standalone function.

Comment: +1 This is on target.  We use staticmethods to attach regular functions to a class.  This improved findability for a function that is strongly related to a class but doesn't depend on it.

Comment: So if a have a function with two characteristics - standalone and semantically related to a class.
To obey the characteristic of semantical similarity, I should put it inside a class.
To obey the characteristic of standalone, I should use a `@staticmethod` decorator instead of passing a dummy `self` argument in it since the argument `self` somehow fades away its color of standalone. But afterall, no much  performance gain, right?

Comment: @user2720402: Roughly, yes, if I understand you right.  Performance is not a reason to use or not use a staticmethod.  You should choose whether or not to use a staticmethod based on the function's conceptual relation with a class (or lack thereof).

Comment: Even when I don't add @staticmethod the functions still work even without the decorator. Is tehre any advantage to it?

Answer (score 25):

Today I suddenly find a benefit of using `@staticmethod`.

If you created a staticmethod within a class, you don't need to create an instance of the class before using the staticmethod.

For example,

```
class File1:
    def __init__(self, path):
        out=self.parse(path)

    def parse(self, path):
        ..parsing works..
        return x

class File2:
    def __init__(self, path):
        out=self.parse(path)

    @staticmethod
    def parse(path):
        ..parsing works..
        return x

if __name__=='__main__':
    path='abc.txt'
    File1.parse(path) #TypeError: unbound method parse() ....
    File2.parse(path) #Goal!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Since the method `parse` is strongly related to the classes `File1` and `File2`, it is more natural to put it inside the class. However, sometimes this `parse` method may also be used  in other classes under some circumstances. If you want to do so using `File1`, you must create an instance of `File1` before calling the method `parse`. While using staticmethod in the class `File2`, you may directly call the method by using the syntax `File2.parse`.

This makes your works more convenient and natural.

Comment: This is all also true of `@classmethod`. The distinction is that `@classmethod`s get passed the class instance and `@staticmethod`s don't get passed anything special.

Comment: Can't you remove `@staticmethod` and get the same result?

Answer (score 3):

I will add something other answers didn't mention. It's not only a matter of modularity, of putting something next to other logically related parts. It's also that the method could be non-static at other point of the hierarchy (i.e. in a subclass or superclass) and thus participate in polymorphism (type based dispatching). So if you put that function outside the class you will be precluding subclasses from effectively overriding it. Now, say you realize you don't need `self` in function `C.f` of class `C`, you have three two options:

1. Put it outside the class. But we just decided against this.
2. Do nothing new: while unused, still keep the `self` parameter.
3. Declare you are not using the `self` parameter, while still letting other `C` methods to call `f` as `self.f`, which is required if you wish to keep open the possibility of further overrides of `f` that do depend on some instance state.

Option 2 demands less conceptual baggage (you already have to know about `self` and methods-as-bound-functions, because it's the more general case). But you still may prefer to be explicit about `self` not being using (and the interpreter could even reward you with some optimization, not having to partially apply a function to `self`). In that case, you pick option 3 and add `@staticmethod` on top of your function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@staticmethod` for methods that don't need to operate on a specific object, but that you still want located in the scope of the class (as opposed to module scope).

Your example in `test2.static_add_one` wastes its time passing an unused `self` parameter, but otherwise works the same as `test1.static_add_one`. Note that this extraneous parameter can't be optimized away.

One example I can think of is in a Django project I have, where a model class represents a database table, and an object of that class represents a record. There are some functions used by the class that are stand-alone and do not need an object to operate on, for example a function that converts a title into a "slug", which is a representation of the title that follows the character set limits imposed by URL syntax. The function that converts a title to a slug is declared as a `staticmethod` precisely to strongly associate it with the class that uses it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you hit it on the head here:

> But at the same time, the method `static_add_one` in the class `test2` which has no `@staticmethod` decoration also works properly by using a trick that provides a `self` in the argument but doesn't use it at all.

As you said, `@staticmethod` provides the `self` parameter implicitly so that you can call the method from an instance instead of the class and not have to explicitly write the `self` parameter. Per https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod:

> A static method can be called either on the class (such as `C.f()`) or on an instance (such as `C().f()`).

For `C().f()` to work, you either need to decorate `f()` with `@staticmethod` (or explicitly call `staticmethod()`) or explicitly add the `self` parameter as you have done in your example.

Comment: This question is almost a decade old with several existing answers. What does this add that isn't already covered?