# Python OOP - Unable to change the value of class variable using self

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_prototype.htm) Python Design pattern, and there is something I don't understand about the initialization() function:

```
class ObjectFactory:

   """ Manages prototypes.
   Static factory, that encapsulates prototype
   initialization and then allows instatiation
   of the classes from these prototypes.
   """

   __type1Value1 = None
   __type1Value2 = None
   __type2Value1 = None
   __type2Value2 = None

   @staticmethod
   def initialize():
      ObjectFactory.__type1Value1 = Type1(1)
      ObjectFactory.__type1Value2 = Type1(2)
      ObjectFactory.__type2Value1 = Type2(1)
      ObjectFactory.__type2Value2 = Type2(2)
```

Why the init for the variables are using the name of the class (i.e. `ObjectFactory.__type1Value1`) and not using self (i.e. `self.__type1Value1`)?
When I changed to self:

```
   def initialize(self):
      self.__type1Value1 = Type1(1)
      self.__type1Value2 = Type1(2)
      self.__type2Value1 = Type2(1)
      self.__type2Value2 = Type2(2)
```

I got error `TypeError: initialize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

But in another example, using "self" worked:

```
class Geek: 

    # Variable defined inside the class. 
    inVar = 'inside_class'
    print("Inside_class2", inVar) 

    def access_method(self): 
        self.inVar="a"
        print("Inside_class3", self.inVar) 

uac = Geek() 
uac.access_method()
```

Output:

```
Inside_class2 inside_class
Inside_class3 a
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please update your question with your call to `initialize()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we use @staticmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508248/why-do-we-use-staticmethod)

Comment: Side note: in the linked design pattern, it would have probably been better to decorate the methods with ``@classmethod`` instead of ``@staticmethod`` to avoid typing the class name. You can read about there difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod

Comment: Frankly speaking, that tutorial does not seem to teach typical Python patterns and conventions.

Comment: This is one more useless tutorial written by someone that has obviously not much experience with the language. Actually the whole serie is just as bad - the part on "the iterator pattern" just shows one simple generator function without even any explanation :facepalm:

Comment: @KlausD. I am more doing reverse engineering than learning about DP :/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Do you have better tutorial to learn DP? My boss asked me to learn DP for python, but I have no experience with DP (with any language), do you have any advice?

Comment: @aronot design patterns are mostly language independant. If you understand the pattern itself - it's principle and the problem it's supposed to solve - and know the language, the effective implementation is just a detail. The best text about design patterns (and possibly one of the best texts about OO design) is still the original: "Design Patterns - 
Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by Gamma, Helm, Johnson and Vlissides (aka "the GOF").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking up the value of an attribute, `self.foo` will fall back to `type(self).foo` (roughly speaking) if there is no instance attribute named `foo`.

When *setting* a value, though, `self.foo` will *always* update (or create, if necessary) an instance attribute. You have to explicitly refer to the class to modify a class attribute.

In your other example, `self` "worked" in the sense that you verified the value of the new instance attribute `inVar` of `uac`. The class attribute `Geek.inVar` remained unchanged.