# Overwriting save method not working in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, save, django-signals

I have a model (Points) which saves the points based on the purchase made by a user. I have made in such a way that when order is made (orderapi is called), a signal is passed with order instance and points are calculated based on the amount and it is saved using the **save** method.

Alothugh Order object is created, I dont see the points being saved in the database. I am not sure what is the issue.

My models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)   
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)   

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        # abc = sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])
        # print(abc)
        return sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Orders"
        ordering = ('-id',)

class OrderItem(models.Model):       
    orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12, editable=False, default=id_generator)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)    

    @property
    def price(self):
        total_item_price = self.quantity * self.order_variants.price
        # print(total_item_price)
        return total_item_price    

    

class Points(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    points_gained = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def collect_points(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        total_price = instance.total_price
        if created:
            if total_price <= 10000:
                abc = 0.01 * total_price
            else:
                abc = 0.75 * total_price
            return abc

    post_save.connect(collect_points,sender=Order)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.points_gained = self.collect_points()
        super(Points, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am actually confused here. Can we access property total_price using instance.total_price??

My serializers:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    #total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_total_price')
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','user','ordered_date','order_status', 'ordered', 'order_items','total_price', 'billing_details']
        # depth = 1   

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.is_seller:
            order_items = validated_data.pop('order_items')
            billing_details = validated_data.pop('billing_details')
            order = Order.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
            BillingDetails.objects.create(user=user,order=order,**billing_details)
            for order_items in order_items:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,**order_items)
            order.save()
            return order
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This is not a customer account.Please login as customer.")
```

**My updated code:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)

    def final_price(self):      
        return  sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = self.final_price()
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Points(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    points_gained = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def collect_points(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        total_price = instance.total_price
        print(total_price)
        if created:
            if total_price <= 10000:
                abc = 0.01 * total_price
            else:
                abc = 0.75 * total_price
        new_point = Points.objects.create(order=instance, points_gained=abc)

    post_save.connect(collect_points,sender=Order)
```

**Focused on this part**

```
Class Order(models.Model):
    total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)

    def final_price(self):
        # abc = sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])
        # print(abc)
        return  sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = self.final_price()
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

While you did put it WITHIN your `Point` model, it does not affect it. It is linked to the `Order` model. If I were to translate your signal in English, it would be: *After saving a `Order` instance, calculate and return the `abc` variable*.

At no point whatsoever are we saving or interacting with the `Point` model here. So, even though you did override the `Point.save()` method, you're not calling it in relation to your signal

If you want to do is to create `Point` instance:

```py
def collect_points(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    total_price = instance.total_price
    if created:
        if total_price <= 10000:
            abc = 0.01 * total_price
        else:
            abc = 0.75 * total_price
        # ---> Now we can create the point
        new_point = Points.objects.create(order=instance, points_gained=abc)

post_save.connect(collect_points,sender=Order)

# And no need to override the save() method
```

So now, our signal means *After saving an `Order` instance, if it was created, calculate the points and create a `Point` instance from this data*

Also, here's some additional tips to make your life easier when dealing with signals:

- Create a `signals.py` file. It's best for long-term management to group your signal in a specific file
- Put your signal code there
- You can use decorators on your functions to make them signals, like `@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)`
- In your `apps.py` file, in your app class, override the `ready` method to import the signals. The `ready` method is automatically triggered when booting the app. So it's like "do this on boot". In our case, we'll be registering the signals on boot. Snippet example:

```py
#apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class SecurityConfig(AppConfig):

    name = "security"
    label = "security"

    def ready(self):
        """Imports signals on application start"""

        import security.signals
```

---

EDIT: Using a class method and a standalone signal

```py
# In models.py
class Points(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    points_gained = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    @classmethod
    def create_point_from_order(cls, order_instance):
        """Creates a Points instance from an order"""
        total_price = order_instance.total_price
        if total_price <= 10000:
            abc = 0.01 * total_price
        else:
            abc = 0.75 * total_price
        return cls.objects.create(order=order_instance, points_gained=abc)
```

Then you can create a signal on the `Order` model which calls that method

```py
# In signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Order, Points


@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def create_point_for_order(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """On Order creation, creates a matching Points instance"""
    if created:
        created_point = Points.create_point_from_order(instance)
```

Finally, we register that signal by making sure the `signals.py` file is called on boot

```py
# In apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class YourAppNameConfig(AppConfig):

    name = "your.app.name"
    label = "your.app.name"

    def ready(self):
        import yourappname.signals
```

That way:

- The logic is still in the model, in the `create_point_from_order` method
- That allows us to split logic from signal, and make it re-usable
- And then we simply register an `Order` signal whose job is to simply call that point creation method

Comment: Hello @Jordan, def collect_points should be inside Points model right?? Can you check my updated code. I now defined total_price as a field instead of property but it is saving 0, always when order is created.

Comment: A `signal` is simply a way of doing au automatic action when a model is created/saved/destroy. In that signal, you can then do whatever you want. In your case, you want a signal triggered by `Order`, and the action is to create `Point`. Let me update my answer with an example on how to properly do it

Comment: I am sorry, but I confused. With my little knowledge, what I have gather is I should create signals in Points model not in order model. Also, cant I use normal function? Is it really necrssary to use classmethod??

Comment: What I'd suggest is: creating a `signals.py` file and put your signal in there, not in the models. As for the function, you COULD use a normal function, but if that function is suppose to output a NEW instance, it makes more sense to create a `classmethod` rather than a normal method. I'll update my post with more detail for the code

Comment: I've updated my answer and provided more detail for `signals.py` and `apps.py`. The idea is that: the LOGIC is in the model (`create_point_for_order`), the SIGNALS are in the `signals.py` (and eventually call your model logic), and the signals are REGISTERED at launch because they are imported in the `ready` method of your app config

Comment: Thank you so much @Jordan, but I am really concerned in a small thing. I have put my updated code as focused code. I am just simply confused on why the total_price isnt being saved. It is saved as zero. It only shows value if I used it as a property. I have removed the signals part in Point model for now. Can you please check it??

Comment: Your code is not indented properly. The `new_point = Points.objects.create(order=instance, points_gained=abc)` is not within the `created` condition. So, if `created`, abc has value, but if NOT created, that line is still called but `abc` does not exist

Comment: No, I am talking about the Order part. I called final_price function and tried to save it to the total_price using save, but the price is zero. I am not talking about Point model part. Please can you check the " Focused on this part" of my code at last.

Comment: Alright I think I found it. In your serializer, you are creating then `Order` instance (and saving it) BEFORE it has `OrderedItems`. So when you save it, it has no `OrderedItems` and its `total_price` is set to 0. You'd need to re-save it AFTER you added the `OrderedItems`, so that its full_price gets recomputed

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I was able to save the total_price into db. But, can you please tell me what is this cls. Cant we used Points.objects.create??

Comment: We are using `Points.objects.create`. This is what `cls.objects.create` means, because `cls` here is `Points`. The difference between a `classmethod` and a normal method, is that the `classmethod` is performed on the class itself, while the normal method is performed on the instance. It's `Points.method` vs `Points().method`.

Comment: In our case, we want to create a new `Points` from an `Order`. We dont have any points yet. So it makes sense to use the `Points` class, and not a `Points` instance. We use the `@classmethod` decorator to say `This method uses the class object, not the instance`. Now, the reason we're making that method is because we want to perform some logic before calling the `Points.objects.create`. But that last line `cls.objects.create` IS EXACTLY `Points.objects.create`. Because we are WITHIN the `Points` class, so `cls` == `Points`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232143/discussion-between-sp-django-and-jordan-kowal).

Comment: Hello @Jordan, my points_gained is zero in db everytime, can you please check the issue??

Comment: Did you update your serializer following my previous comment? `Order.total_price` is calculated based on `save` based on its `OrderedItem`. But in the serializer, when you create and save the `Order`, it has no `OrderedItem` yet (because they havent been created), so its `total_price` is `0`. Once you've created the items, you need to re-save the `Order` so that its total gets updated.

Comment: Yes @Jordan, I have put order.save() after Items were created. After this, total_price starts showing the value as it was zero too. But the points_gained still remain zero. I am stuck.

Comment: Oh, I got it. The issue is that your signal code is nested in `created`. When you FIRST save the `Order`, it is created, so you create your `Points` instance using its total which is 0. Then, when you re-save the `Order` to update its total, the signal is called but `created=False`, so you do nothing. You'd need to update the signal so that you can UPDATE the EXISTING `Points` instance. Or implement it differently

Comment: Yes that is the issue I know, so that means, I simply calculate the points writing is created==False. Will that work?? Because I have other another update order api, which is called. Will it affect it??

Comment: The signal will be called whenever the `Order` instance is saved. If you want to calculate `Points` at specific times, there are several ways: using signals with conditional, or simply doing it within the `create` serializer, etc. You must figure out which workflows you want and then try to implement them

Comment: Hello @Jordan Kowal, can you please have a look into it?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622998/how-to-append-the-fields-inside-an-array-to-a-formdata-in-react

Answer (score 1):

This is one clear example, where signals are not a good fit. Both models are already under your control, you are already overriding the Order save method. There is **zero** need for this work to use a signal and it only complicates things.

This is the simple approach:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)

    def final_price(self):      
        return  sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items.all()])

    def save(self, force_insert=False, **kwargs):
        created = force_insert or not self.pk
        self.total_price = self.final_price()
        super(Order, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, **kwargs)
        if created:
            points = Points.calculate_points(self.total_price)
            Points.objects.create(order=self, points_gained=points)

class Points(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(
        Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True
    )
    points_gained = models.FloatField(default=0)

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_points(amount):
        return 0.01 * amount if amount <= 10000 else 0.75 * amount
```

### How do signals work?

Signals are ways for libraries to inject arbitrary code into a piece of code they control:

```py
# Somebody else's code, you cannot modify
def greeting():
    print('Hello ')
    send_signal('after_print_hello')
    print('!')
```

Now this code has some way to register with the 'after_print_hello' signal, this is called the receiver:

```py
# Your code
def on_after_print_hello():
    print('world')
```

So in the end this happens:

```
def greeting():
    print('Hello ')
    print('world') <-----------\
    print('!')                 |
                               |
def on_after_print_hello():    |
    print('world')  -----------/
```

It seems absolute nonsense to use signals here, if both parts of the code are yours. You can just move the print statement to where you want it.

And if you take away all the fancy registration and receiver matching, this is exactly what is happening with Django signals as well. These `post_save` signals are only useful, if you want to add extra steps in models that are *not* yours, after the models are saved. If you're using them for your own models, you're just moving the `print('world')` statement to a different place and use Django to call it for you using a more involved API.

Comment: so we cant use signals, when the sender instance is overwritten by save method? Is that what you are saying? Can you check my updated code please? It works but price is zero and so is points. Also, if I use property instead, I get the total_price.

Comment: I'm saying you don't have to. It complicates things. Your updated code, has put you further away from the solution.

Comment: ok. But do we have to use @staticmethod ?? I have never used it. Cant we just call the function name without using satticmethod??

Comment: Yes. Don't be afraid. It won't hurt. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23508293) for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much @Melvyn, but I am really concerned in a small thing. I have put my updated code as focused code. I am just simply confused on why the total_price isnt being saved. It is saved as zero. It only shows value if I used it as a property. I have removed the signals part in Point model for now. Can you please check it??

Comment: Hello @Melvyn, from your code , we can save the points gained from that order, but what I need is to add the existing points from the points gained. How can we achieve that??

Comment: Hello @Melvyn, I tried your code, but every time when I check db, the points_gained is zero althought total_price is not. What is the issue can you please check??

Comment: Hello @Melvyn can you please have a look into it?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622998/how-to-append-the-fields-inside-an-array-to-a-formdata-in-react I am stuck.